# Spyder - hints disappear too fast

Tags: python, ide, spyder

So I'm using Spyder as my Python IDE. It has a great feature which are hints, f.e when I type `numpy.arange(` it shows me, that I need to insert `stop, start, step` etc. But it appears on screen, and disappears after like 2-3s, and most of the times I don't manage to read the whole thing, but anyways I would still like to see it, just to think about what should I type. So is there a way to extend the timeout of those hints, or make them stay there until f.e I close the parentheses?

P.S Am I having delusions, or is IPython interpreter much faster than simple Python command line interpreter?

P.S2 Is there a way, to make Spyder do auto-indentation (f.e after going to a new line inside of a function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FryninoS,

If you put your mouse over the information box it will stay open until you move the mouse off the box.

Austin.